# Game "Need for Speed Most Wanted" can't controlled by Java class Robot

Tags: java

I wrote a bot for controlling racing game using Java Robot. The bot works well for *Need For Speed Underground* except for key "Down" (Up, Left, Right keys work very well). However my bot can't control *Need For Speed Most Wanted*.

The bot works fine, but the Game doesn't accept the simulated key events. I did some searching, and found the game is DirectX based. In DirectX the keyboard/mouse events are special. It seems that the game "asks" the keyboard directly, not through Windows. And I try my program in CS, and found it works pretty well.

I program in Windows 7, using Eclipse and Java 1.6. So I want to ask why doesn't *Need for Speed Most Wanted* accept the simulated key events and how to solve this program? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrote a bot for controlling racing
>   game using Java Robot.

What KeyEvents to you generate?

> For Java Robot's simulated key events
>   like "VK_Up,
>   VK_Down,Vk_Left,VK_Right", the "Need
>   for Speed Most Wanted" ignored. But,
>   for keys "A-Z", the game accepted!

Maybe you are trying to generate keyTyped events when you should be using keyPressed and keyReleased?

Here is a simple example that works with the right/left/up down keys. Try entering (1, 2, 3) then backspace to the beginning and enter (0). Then press the playback button.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RobotPlayback extends JFrame implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{
    JTextField textField1;
    JTextField textField2;
    List playback = new ArrayList();

    public RobotPlayback()
    {
        textField1 = new JTextField(30);
        textField1.addKeyListener( this );
        getContentPane().add(textField1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
//
        JButton button = new JButton("Playback");
        button.addActionListener( this );
        button.setFocusable(false);
        getContentPane().add(button);
//
        textField2 = new JTextField(30);
        getContentPane().add(textField2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        playback.add(e);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        playback.add(e);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Thread playback = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                 playback();
            }
        };
        playback.start();
    }

    private void playback()
    {
        textField2.requestFocus();

        try
        {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.setAutoDelay( 200 );

            for (int i = 0; i < playback.size();i++)
            {
                KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)playback.get(i);

                if (event.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
                    robot.keyPress( event.getKeyCode() );
                else
                    robot.keyRelease( event.getKeyCode() );
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }

        setVisible(true);
        playback = new ArrayList();
        textField1.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        JFrame frame = new RobotPlayback();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
     }
}
```

> I registered the account just in this
>   morning and 11 reputations only. Not
>   enough for upvoting

Even with 11 points you should be able to "accept" an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: I wrote a testing program to accept the key events from the bot. The results show that keyPressed, keyReleased and keyTyped are all triggered. I don't get your point. And thank your for your advice. I remember that. ^_^

Comment: My point was that you said the key A-Z worked. Well these key strokes will generate a keyTyped event since they are displayable characters. On the other hand the arrow keys do not generate displayable characters so even if the keyTyped event is generated it will contain an undefined value for the key typed character. Maybe this is causing a problem in your code. If you notice my Robot only tracks keyPressed and keyReleased events so it doesn't worry about keyTyped events. Don't know if it makes a difference or not, but maybe you can ignore the keyTyped events.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, DirectX doesn't rely on the events generated by Windows to receive input from the keyboard. Thus, firing simulated events won't work for you. I don't think you can do what you want.

Comment: NO! How am I supposed to cheat at my games?

Comment: I was debugging my program till last minute. Big surprise found! For Java Robot's simulated key events like "VK_Up, VK_Down,Vk_Left,VK_Right", the "Need for Speed Most Wanted" ignored. But, for keys "A-Z", the game accepted! Now my program works pretty well as I reset the keys for Speed. Maybe for arrow keys, there exits different handle methods.

Comment: I want to do that. But I registered the account just in this morning and 11 reputations only. Not enough for upvoting. So I thanks using a comment

Answer (score 2):

The Java Robot has a bug when it comes to arrow keys.  It will be pressing the num pad arrows.  Currently, it is not possible to press the non num pad arrows.

Ref:  https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4838497

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question, I'll post my answer in case it helps someone out later.

I recently faced the same issue. I was calling keyPress and keyRelease right after the other for each of the left, right, up and down keys, based on some external input. I tried a bunch of games, but the Robot key presses didn't work in any of them. When I tried the same code with the cursor in a text file, the cursor moved correctly.

The problem was that games typically require continuous key presses, and so the keyPress+keyRelease combination didn't cause any effect. So I fixed the issue by calling keyRelease in the opposite direction for each arrow key press.

For instance, if the left arrow key needed to be pressed, I call

> `keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);`
>   `keyPress(KeyEVent.VK_LEFT);`

This keeps the left key pressed till the right arrow key eventually needs to be pressed. There are more optimal ways to do this by tracking the last key press, and so on, but this method seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is a very old post but my answer might be helpful for someone who is looking for answer*

**Answer:-**

Its because some games uses **DirectInput API** for reading keyboard **scan codes** rather than virtual key codes. As **java.awt.Robot** performs keystrokes via virtual key codes not scan codes therefore keyboard events simulated using **java.awt.Robot** may have not effect on the game. You have to make Windows native call from your java application using JNI/JNA.

code is available here [https://github.com/umer0586/winKeyboad](https://github.com/umer0586/winKeyboard)

```
Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
keyboard.winKeyPress(ScanCode.DIK_UP);
//Thread.sleep(1000);
keyboard.winKeyRelease(ScanCode.DIK_UP);
```